# Disable swipe feature of ios app which moves it to previous screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think this is the os level feature in ios, using which user can move back to previous screen by just swiping current view to right side. It just require to touch left edge of a view and move it in right direction. You can see it in below screenshot.

[image: moving back to previous screen by just swiping]

The problem is that it causes the logged in user to logout just by swiping screen left to right, though there is not any back button on logged in screen. It is badly affecting my app's whole functionality.

Does anybody know how to disable this moving back feature on swipe and restrict it to back button only?

Comment: no need to comment @DarshanKunjadiya, he's already notified by your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your view controller.

**Swift 5**

```
if navigationController?.responds(to: #selector(UINavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer)) ?? false {
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}
```

**Objective C**

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: This works great but has been giving me some grief with `touchesBegan` events not firing on controls that exist inside a ~15pt border around the ViewController. Anything not on the border of the VC works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT**

`self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false`

Comment: Please add some explanation why you think this is a correct solution.

Comment: Because this was already marked as correct answer above, but Darshan wrote only answer for objC, and I put here the Swift version. Now I see someone edited Darshan's answer and added a Swift 5 version.

Answer (score 0):

We can Disable or Enable on **iOS 7 and above**.

In *UIKit framework*

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
open var interactivePopGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer? { get }
```

So, You just disable the gesture by setting true or false for navigationController.

Once you enable or disable that will affect the every screens interactive gestures.

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```